# How can I manipulate data in a list where date and price are in the same list item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am quite lost on this homework assignment and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a list of dates and the price per gallon of gas on that date. An example list is shown below, but the dates in the file are from 1993 - 2013.

- 04-05-1993:1.068
- 04-12-1993:1.079
- 01-03-1994:0.992
- 01-10-1994:0.995
- 01-02-1995:1.127
- 01-09-1995:1.134

At this point, I am able to read the file, but I have no clue how to work with that data once it's in a list. Up to this point, I've only worked with a single piece of data in a list.

```
file = open('GasPrices.txt','r')

file_contents = file.read()
get_words = file_contents.split()
print(get_words)
```

The goal is to get average price per year, average price per month, highest and lowest prices for each year (showing date and amount), list of prices highest to lowest and list of prices lowest to highest.

I don't think I'll have an issue mathing those items, but I'm really struggling to understand how I can "break apart" the date from the price and then after doing the math for the items mentioned above, printing the dollar amount with the date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Repeat your materials on string handling; any tutorial on strings will include the methods available to manipulate them.  Look for `split`.

Comment: Start by thinking about how you would manipulate one of the lines from the file, if you only had that line as a single string. Also, if you really want to treat the file as containing *lines* rather than *words*, please look at e.g. the `.readlines()` method for files.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list for each item, and use `date, price = item.split(':')` . This will allow you to split by the ":", and assign each part to different variables.

`split(':')` is creating a list with all the pieces of the string that are split by the semicolon.

I would do something like this though:

```
with open('GasPrice.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
data = [line.split(':') for line in lines]
```

The text in the file is split by each new line, and then the data list is created by splitting each line by the semicolon.